# Typescript + Styled-Components + Styled-System: No overload matches this call

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components, styled-system

so I get the famous "No overload matches this call" error when using Typescript + Styled-Components + Styled-System.

The solutions I found so far require me to pass a generic `type/interface` to the styled component. Which I do with the `ButtonProps`. So what am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

**styled-system type imports**

```
import {
  background,
  BackgroundProps,
  border,
  BorderProps,
  color,
  ColorProps,
  layout,
  LayoutProps,
  shadow,
  ShadowProps,
  typography,
  TypographyProps,
  variant
} from "styled-system"
```

**Type declaration**

```
interface VariantProps {
  variant: "submit" | "cancel"
}

type ButtonProps = BackgroundProps &
  BorderProps &
  ColorProps &
  LayoutProps &
  ShadowProps &
  TypographyProps &
  VariantProps
```

**Styled component definition**

```
const Button = styled.button<ButtonProps>`
  ${background}
  ${border}
  ${color}
  ${layout}
  ${shadow}
  ${typography}
  ${({
    disabled,
    theme
  }) => variant({
    variants: {
      submit: {
        background: theme.gradients.blue,
        border: "none",
        borderRadius: "sm",
        boxShadow: "0px 10px 5px -5px rgba(93,159,255, 0.3);",
        color: theme.colors.white,
        cursor: disabled ? "not-allowed" : "default",
        fontSize: "sm",
        fontWeight: 600,
        my: "16px",
        minHeight: "50px",
        opacity: disabled ? 0.5 : 1,
      }
    }
  })}
`;
```

**Usage of the styled component and where the error occurs** (`<Button {...props}>`)

```
const AnimatedButton: React.FC<ButtonProps> = ({
  children,
  ...props
}) => {
  return (
    <Button {...props}>
      {children}
    </Button>
  )
}
```

Screenshot of the error message
[image: Overload error]

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. See: "[How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)". "[Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/128421)"
and "[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812)" are also pertinent.

Answer (score -3):

Try this

`const Button = styled(button)<ButtonProps>`

Comment: Hey Mate, that can't work I guess, since ``button`` won't be defined.

Comment: Ok, let me dig into this

Comment: It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.

Comment: The solution is not working anyways. Couldn't find a solution so far.